# Mobile App Authentication on asp.net mvc controler

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

S**Problem to solve:**

So I'm building my first mobile app using nomad and I have pages I want to call through ajax. The problem is I need an authenticated user to get the data I'm looking for. I'm just using the built in forms authentication logic that comes built into mvc 3 projects. So how can I securely authorize a user on a mobile device and keep them logged in while making calls later?

**Environment:**

I'm using a tool http://vsnomad.com/, for my app, and a basic asp.net mvc 3 site controller to login and get the data the app needs. I'm not using webpi just a controler to keep it simply for now. For the mobile app its built on jquery, jquery mobile, and HTML 5, any help here would be much appreciated

Comment: Why do you think a mobile web browser would be different then a non-mobile web browser in terms of authorization or authentication?